# QGIS - Problem with exporting an edited Excel file (.txt) as a shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, export, import

I'm having a problem with exporting an edited Excel file (.txt) as a shapefile..

Here's the workflow:

I've created a new vector layer with 5 dots --> I export the layer data to excel and add 2 new dots/coordinates --> Import the 7 coordinates as a "txt seperated" layer to QGIS --> Right click the txt layer in the layer menu --> save as --> and click in all the essential things...

It doesn't save as a shapefile, I get this error message:

> Export to vector layer failed.
> Error: Saving metadata to the specified uri is not supported

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you try saving in another format? Can you try saving to another directory? Can you try saving to another filename? Can you publicly share the data and exact things you manually edited in Excel?

Comment: While the Excel application can interact with CSV and othe text files, that doesn't make them Excel files. Shapefile requires a geometry, which ASCII text is unlikely to have.

Comment: Do you have to use Excel. You can use QGIS to add two new points